# Asp.Net MV3 Razor List Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am new to MV3 Razor development, so my question is about getting started doing what I am attempting to do.

I have a page called _Layout.cshtml. This page starts out by display a View of Index.cshtml that has a model: @model `IEnumerable<Sample.Models.Product>`. This is a Northwind database sample that displays a page of Products.

Now in my _Layout.cshtml page, I want either a listbox or dropdownlistbox that would list Categories. When a Category was selected from the list, the Products would be filtered to display only the Products in that Category.

I have tried creating a new page and displaying it using using `@RenderPage`, with no luck. It seems like the list would need to be displayed in a form, so I was looking at `@Html.BeginForm` but that is where I got lost.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to step back and read a little more about Razor and indeed about ASP.Net MVC.

If you follow through a tutorial like NerdDinner for MVC or [ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) for Razor, then this will help you work forwards.

At a basic level:

- the _Layout.cshtml is like a "master page" for your app - it should contain only the common layout elements for all your pages.
- the Index.cshtml page is where you can put the listbox or dropdown list - take a look around for samples that use @Html.DropDownListFor()

Razor and MVC are superb - hope you enjoy learning and using them.